# Finding roots of quadratic equation

Tags: java

I have this code so far but every time i run and put the three numbers in a get the roots are NaN can some one please help or point me to where i went wrong.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class Quadratic {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println("Enter three coefficients");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   double a = sc.nextDouble();
   double b = sc.nextDouble();
   double c = sc.nextDouble();
   double root1= (-b + Math.sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c ) )/ (2*a);
   double root2= (-b - Math.sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c ) )/ (2*a);
   System.out.println("The roots1 are: "+ root1);
   System.out.println("The roots2 are: " + root2);


     } 
   }
```

Comment: Are the discriminants negative for the test cases that you're running?

Comment: Maybe if you print a, b and c out before doing the calculation, it will give you a clue or at least rule out some possible problems.

Comment: It is suppose to be positive discriminant

Comment: Is it? What if `a`, `b`, and `c` are each equal to 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that not every quadratic equation has roots that can be expressed in terms of real numbers. More specifically, if `b*b - 4*a*c < 0`, then the roots will have an imaginary part and `NaN` will be returned, since `Math.sqrt` of a negative number returns `NaN`, as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29). This works for coefficients such that `b*b - 4*a*c >= 0`, however:

```
Enter three coefficients
1
5
6
The roots1 are: -2.0
The roots2 are: -3.0
```

---

If you wanted to account for non-real roots as well, you could do something like

```
double d = (b * b - 4 * a * c);
double re = -b / (2 * a);

if (d >= 0) {  // i.e. "if roots are real"
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(d) / (2 * a) + re);
    System.out.println(-Math.sqrt(d) / (2 * a) + re);
} else {
    System.out.println(re + " + " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2 * a)) + "i");
    System.out.println(re + " - " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2 * a)) + "i");
}
```

Comment: So the OP could add a test for >= 0 or print out its value or both and that would make it clear to just apply the equation in cases where it applies.

Comment: I understand all of that but how would i change to make it b*b-4ac>0? With out having to show the non-real roots

Comment: @user1982007 What do you mean? What do you want to do if the user enters numbers `a`, `b`, `c` such that `b*b-4ac < 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps--

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
class QuadraticCalculator  
{   
public static void main(String args[])  
{

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);  
    double a,b,c,quad_dis,quad_11,quad_1,quad_21,quad_2;  
    System.out.println("Enter the value of A");  
    a=s.nextDouble();  
    System.out.println("\nEnter the value of B");  
    b=s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("\nEnter the value of C");
    c=s.nextDouble();
    quad_dis=b*b-4*a*c;
    quad_11=(-1*b)+(Math.sqrt(quad_dis));
    quad_1=quad_11/(2*a);
    quad_21=(-1*b)-(Math.sqrt(quad_dis));
    quad_2=quad_21/(2*a);
    int choice;
    System.out.println("\n\nWhat do you want to do with the numbers you entered ?\n(1) Calculate Discriminant\n(2) Calculate the values\n(3) Find the nature of roots\n(4) All of the above");
    choice=s.nextInt();
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: System.out.println("\nDiscriminant: "+quad_dis);
                break;
        case 2: System.out.println("\nValues are: "+quad_1+", "+quad_2);
                break;
        case 3: if(quad_dis>0)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThe roots are REAL and DISTINCT");
                }
                else if(quad_dis==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThe roots are REAL and EQUAL");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThe roots are IMAGINARY");
                }
                break;
        case 4: System.out.println("\nDiscriminant: "+quad_dis);
                System.out.println("\nValues are: "+quad_1+", "+quad_2);
                if(quad_dis>0)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThe roots are REAL and DISTINCT");
                }
                else if(quad_dis==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThe roots are REAL and EQUAL");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThe roots are IMAGINARY");
                }
                break;

    }
    System.out.println("\n\nThank You for using this Calculator");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. First, it will check whether input equation is quadratic or not. And if input equation is quadratic then it will find roots.
This code is able to find complex roots too.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    // Declaration of variables
    float a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, disc, sq_dis;
    float[] root = new float[2];
    StringBuffer number;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Input equation from user
    System.out.println("Enter Equation in form of ax2+bx+c");
    String equation = scan.nextLine();

    // Regex for quadratic equation
    Pattern quadPattern = Pattern.compile("(([+-]?\\d*)[Xx]2)+((([+-]?\\d*)[Xx]2)*([+-]\\d*[Xx])*([+-]\\d+)*)*|((([+-]?\\d*)[Xx]2)*([+-]\\d*[Xx])*([+-]\\d+)*)*(([+-]?\\d*)[Xx]2)+|((([+-]?\\d*)[Xx]2)*([+-]\\d*[Xx])*([+-]\\d+)*)*(([+-]?\\d*)[Xx]2)+((([+-]?\\d*)[Xx]2)*([+-]\\d*[Xx])*([+-]\\d+)*)*");
    Matcher quadMatcher = quadPattern.matcher(equation);
    scan.close();

    // Checking if given equation is quadratic or not
    if (!(quadMatcher.matches())) { 
        System.out.println("Not a quadratic equation");
    } 

    // If input equation is quadratic find roots
    else { 

        // Splitting equation on basis of sign
        String[] array = equation.split("(?=[+-])");
        for (String term : array) {
            int len = term.length();
            StringBuffer newTerm = new StringBuffer(term);

            // If term ends with x2, then delete x2 and convert remaining term into integer
            if (term.endsWith("X2") || (term.endsWith("x2"))) {
                number = newTerm.delete(len - 2, len);
                a += Integer.parseInt(number.toString());
            }
            // If term ends with x, then delete x and convert remaining term into integer
            else if (term.endsWith("X") || (term.endsWith("x"))) {
                number = newTerm.deleteCharAt(len - 1);
                b += Integer.parseInt(number.toString());
            }
            // If constant,then convert it into integer
            else {
                c += Integer.parseInt(term);
            }
        }
        // Display value of a,b,c and complete equation
        System.out.println("Coefficient of x2: " + a);
        System.out.println("Coefficient of x: " + b);
        System.out.println("Constent term: " + c);
        System.out.println("The given equation is: " + a + "x2+(" + b + ")x+(" + c + ")=0");

        // Calculate discriminant
        disc = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
        System.out.println(" Discriminant= " + disc);

        // square root of discriminant
        sq_dis = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.abs(disc));

        // conditions to find roots

        if (disc > 0) {
            root[0] = (-b + sq_dis) / (2 * a);
            root[1] = (-b - sq_dis) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("Roots are real and unequal");
            System.out.println("Root1= " + root[0]);
            System.out.println("Root2= " + root[1]);
        } 
        else if (disc == 0) {
            root[0] = ((-b) / (2 * a));
            System.out.println("Roots are real and equal");
            System.out.println("Root1=Root2= " + root[0]);
        } 
        else {

             root[0] = -b / (2 * a);
             root[1] = Math.abs((sq_dis) / (2 * a));

            System.out.println("Roots are complex");
            System.out.println("ROOT1= " + root[0] + "+" + root[1] + "+i");
            System.out.println("ROOT2= " + root[0] + "-" + root[1] + "+i");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
else {
    if ((Math.sqrt(-d) / (2*a)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(r + " + " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2*a)) + " i");
        System.out.println(r + " - " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2*a)) + " i");
    }
    else if ((Math.sqrt(-d) / (2*a)) == 0){
        System.out.println(r);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(r + " - " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2*a)) + " i");
        System.out.println(r + " + " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2*a)) + " i");
    }
```